Looking for a second hand iPhone
I develop software and I have always used Android.  For the first time, I need to develop something for Apple, so I need to test it on an iPhone.
I am looking for

A reasonably new model that is still supported by AppStore.
At least 12cm X 6cm screen (5" by 2.5")
At least 32GB memory
At most $400 AUD

Any suggestions?
